# linear programming problem using python scipy minimize

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I am trying to optimise, using python `scipy.optimize.minimize`, the calorie intake of a person using available food items and sticking to a budget.

The problem statement is: There are n food items, each available in different quantities. Their price changes everyday. Each has a different nutrition value which reduces every day. I need to buy food over a month so that total nutrition is closest to my target and I use my exact monthly budget to buy them.

```
#df_available has 1 row each for each item's available quantity at the beginning of the month
#df_bought has initial guesses for purchase of each item for each day of the month. This is based on prorated allotment of my total budget to each item on each day.
#df_price has price of each item on each day of the month.
#df_nutrition['nutrition'] has initial nutrition value per unit. it decreases by 1 unit each year, so 1/365 each day.
#strt is start date of the month.
#tot_nutrition is monthly total nutrition target for the month
#tot_budget is my monthly budget

def obj_func():
    return (df_bought.sum()*(df_nutrition['nutrition'] - strt/365).sum())

#constraint 1 makes sure that I buy exactly at my budget
def constraint1():
    return ((df_bought * df_price).sum().sum()- tot_budget)
cons1 = {'type':'eq', 'fun':constraint1}

#constraint 2 makes sure that I dont buy more than available quantity of any item
def constraint2():
    return df_available - df_bought
cons2 = {'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraint2}

cons = ([cons1, cons2])

#bounds ensure that I dont buy negative quantity of any item
bnds = (0, None)

res = minimize(obj_func, df_bought_nominal_m, bounds= bnds, constraints=cons)
print(res)
```

For output, i would like the df_bought values to be adjusted to minimise the obj_function.

The code gives the following error:

```
TypeError: constraint1() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

apologies if I am making any rookie mistakes. I am new to python and couldn't find appropriate help online for this problem.

Comment: Your objective function (and the others too) need to be defined in such a way that their parameters are accessable from outside the function. e.g. `def obj_func(bought, nutrition, start_d):` then use the parameter handles to define your function execution.

Comment: `scipy.optimize.minimize` is not for linear programming but for nonlinear problems. The LP solver is `scipy.optimize.linprog`. See the documentation.